# Opengraph HTTP 301 redirect wrong location

Tags: nginx, facebook-opengraph

Open the [opengraph debugger page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808000138/https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) and try it with this url: `http://www.jetradar.com/?marker=12345` - I get this as a result: http://screencloud.net/v/rHlW - for some reason it tries this obviously wrong redirect url "http://www.jetradar.com/,%20http://www.jetradar.com/" though ask the server via `curl` - you get nothing suspicious.

```
$ curl -v http://www.jetradar.com/?marker=12345
* Adding handle: conn: 0x20e9b20
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x20e9b20) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.jetradar.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 5.10.84.53...
* Connected to www.jetradar.com (5.10.84.53) port 80 (#0)
> GET /?marker=12345 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: www.jetradar.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.5.12 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.5.12
< Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 12:43:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.jetradar.com/
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Set-Cookie: marker=12345; path=/; expires=Sun, 07-Dec-2014 12:43:03 GMT
< X-Request-Id: ac8d046ea03191f637cbdf8d9129a1a0
< X-Runtime: 0.011112
< X-Rack-Cache: miss
< X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.19
< Location: http://www.jetradar.com/
< X-Page-Speed: 1.8.31.4-4009
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.jetradar.com left intact
<html><head/><body>You are being <a href="https://www.jetradar.com/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Any ideas?

Hello from jetradar team to stackoverflow community:)

Comment: Haha if you look carefully - you'll notice that there are TWO `Location` headers in response. Don't know how did we manage to do that yet...